# active_record return single associated record for all matching record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, psql

I'm trying to find a way to query my database to return one associated record each for all matching records. e.g:

If a user has many houses, ( a house belongs to a user ), And I need to get all users, with one associated house each ( say the first house ). How do I go about this?

**To expatiate more on this:**

```
user A has houses 1, 2, 3
user B has houses 4, 5, 6
user C has houses 7, 8, 9
```

- to get all users, I can do: `user.all`
- to get all houses of a user, I can do: `<user>.houses`
- to get users with their houses, I can join query: `User.joins(:houses).where(<condition>)`

However, if I want to get all users, and with a house each, in the format:

```
user   |   house
-----------------
A      |   1
B      |   4
C      |   7
```

How can I go about this?

The database is postgres.

**Update:**

My real model is as below:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :product_pictures, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_pictures, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @JaehyunShin psql, postgress database with rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a relation to user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your current code
  has_one :house, -> { where('houses.id IN (SELECT min(id) FROM houses GROUP BY user_id)')}
end
```

Then, your query will be:

```
users = User.joins(:house)
```

**-- Update**
In case you want to filter the result, freely add `where` clause

```
users = User.joins(:house).where(your_filter_conditions)
```

Comment: how about to get all the users? what will the `your_conditions` be in this case?

Comment: Use `your_conditions` if you want to filter the result, check my update, btw `User.joins(:hourse)` is enough to selecting all users with their first hourse!

Comment: can you confirm that this is a query for psql, I'm getting errors.

Comment: Can you show me the error message, this is the query in postgres, just run in my machine successfully!

Comment: The equivalent of the error is: `NameError: uninitialized constant User::Horse`

Comment: Hmm, could you update your models? I think `User::Horse` is another error, since I didn't use any `User::Horse` in my query!

Comment: I just updated the question with my model setup for the relationship

Comment: Hmm maybe my typo error, I wrote `hourse` instead of `house`, anyway, I just updated it, check it out :)

Comment: haha... I saw that. can you see the model setup above in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102654/discussion-between-hieu-pham-and-sunnyk).

Answer (score 0):

```
result = User.joins(:houses).select("users.*, SOMEFUNCTION(houses.id) AS house_id").group(:id)

# you can access single house id like
result.first.house_id
```

You can choose `SOMEFUNCTION` for which house ID you want to select.

If you use postgresql,

```
User.joins(:houses).select("users.*, (array_agg(houses.id))[1] AS house_id").group(:id)
```